# Erro de safe update utilizando stored procedure no MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, stored-procedures

Estou com problemas para atualizar a minha tabela estoque utilizando uma stored procedure no MYSQL.
Segue o código:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `atualiza_estoque`(id_produto int)
BEGIN

update estoque e inner join reposicao r on r.produto = e.produto 
set e.qtd = if (e.qtd = 0, r.qtd, e.qtd+r.qtd), e.data_entrada = now()
where e.produto = id_produto and r.produto=id_produto and r.data_reposicao > e.data_entrada;
END
```

Ao chamar a procedure `call atualiza_estoque(1);`, é exibida a mensagem de erro

**Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column
 To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.**

O engraçado, é que eu consegui executar a procedure duas vezes antes de aparecer essa mensagem. O que estaria causando esse erro? Tentei passar o id do estoque como parâmetro, mas a mesma mensagem aparece.

Obs: Eu sei que é possível desativar o safe update, mas eu gostaria de entender o que está causando esse erro, sendo que a procedure funcionou perfeitamente por duas vezes antes de apresentar o erro.

Answer (score 1):

O erro de safa update vem da necessidade de ter um WHERE que usa a coluna KEY, no caso PRIMARY KEY da tabela a ser alterada. Isso vem como padrão do Workbench, pode ver mais [aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/workbench-faq.html#faq-workbench-delete-safe) Por tanto é garantir que esteja usando a coluna certa no filtro.

A solução rápida para o erro é desabilitar o safe update ou aplicar esse código antes de executar o update:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
```

Também fiz uma alteração na sua consulta, que ficou assim:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `atualiza_estoque`(id_produto int)
BEGIN

    update estoque e 
inner join reposicao r 
        on r.produto = e.produto 
       and r.data_reposicao > e.data_entrada
       set e.qtd = if (e.qtd = 0, r.qtd, e.qtd + r.qtd), e.data_entrada = now()
     where e.produto = id_produto   
END
```

Você pode testar para ver se tudo está funcionando.